# Is my understanding of the definition of closure of a set correct?

Tags: general-topology

We take a set $X$ and define a topology $\tau$ on it. Then we take $A$ a subset of $X$. After that we take those elements or open sets from $\tau$ which completely lies in $A$ and take their intersection. Does this give us the closure points of $A$?

Now please correct me if I was wrong

Comment: Please use some punctuation in your sentence. What is "ta"?

Comment: Ok. It is topology which we define on set X

Comment: Please ignore such small mistakes I am doing all these only because our teachers don't teach us in a proper way the concepts they gave us are totally different when we study such things on Wikipedia or on other search engine. Please try to understand I join this only because I am sure that here experts are available

Comment: You are wrong. The closure of a set is not the intersection of open sets contained inside it. There is no guarantee that such an intersection is even non empty.

Comment: Then please provide me with the correct one. Our papers are just coming and she's is not taking the lectures. We have to cope with it by ourselves

Comment: Also for future reference, if you want to ask if your understanding of a definition is correct then it is always better to include the definition you have been taught. That will make it easier for others to answer you.

Comment: Thanks alot for cooperating I will surely follow your advices

Comment: Keep in mind, enough small mistakes in your question have the effect of making the question incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

A closure of a set A is the smallest closed set containing A . In short it is the intersection of all closed sets containing A.

Answer (score 0):

What you have have written is wrong. First of all every set contains the empty set which is open. Thus your intersection will always be empty. Assuming you meant non empty sets the here is a counter example - consider $\mathbb R$ with usual topology and find the closure of $[0,1]$. We know that $\overline{[0,1]}=[0,1]$. However, the intersection of non-empty open sets contained in $[0,1]$ is clearly empty as $(0,\frac12)$ and $(\frac12,1)$ are disjoint open sets contained in $[0,1]$.

What you are looking for is probably this -

> The closure of a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is the intersection of all closed subsets of $X$ that contain $A$.

One calls a point $x\in X$ a closure point of $A$ if every open set of $X$ that contains $x$ intersects $A$. The set of all closure points of $A$ is called closure of $A$ denoted by $\bar A$.

Let us see how $\bar A= \bigcap_{C\in\mathcal A}C$ where $\mathcal A$ is the set of all closed sets in $X$ that contain $A$.

Let $x\in \bar A$. Let $C$ be a closed set containing $A$. Suppose $x\notin C$. Then $X\setminus C$ is an open set containing $x$ and not intersecting $A$. The contradicts that $x\in \bar A$. Thus $x\in C$. But $C$ was arbitrary. Thus $x\in \bigcap_{C\in\mathcal A}C$

For the reverse inequality you have to show that if $x$ is in every closed set containing $A$ and $U$ is an open set containg $x$ then $U\cap A$ is non empty.

Can you try it for yourself? I will answer if you don't get it.

Comment: The intersection of all CLOSED sets that have $A$ as a subset is the closure of $A.$ That is ,$\bar A=\cap \{B: \bar B=B\supset A\}.$

Comment: That is what I wrote. What are you asking?

Comment: Dear R_D can you please share me your email id I need to ask you very imp questions. Please